# Create a custom many-to-many association - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to make an application to store played FIFA games.

I'm having some trouble setting up the right associations.

I have 2 models at this time, User and Game.

SCHEMA:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160402112419) do

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "home_team_user_id"
    t.integer  "away_team_user_id"
    t.string   "home_score"
    t.string   "away_score"
    t.integer  "winner_id"
    t.integer  "loser_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end

  create_table "games_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "game_id"
  end

  add_index "games_users", ["user_id", "game_id"], name: "index_games_users_on_user_id_and_game_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

MODELS:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

As you can see the "Games" table has 2 corresponding ID's:

- home_team_user_id
- away_team_user_id

These will store the user_id from the Users table, this is needed to calculate who's the winner corresponding with the score.

Console results:

```
irb(main):001:0> Game.last
  Game Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games"  ORDER BY "games"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Game id: 1, home_team_user_id: 1, away_team_user_id: 1, home_score: "1", away_score: "2", winner_id: 1, loser_id: 1, created_at: "2016-04-02 12:27:26", updated_at: "2016-04-02 12:27:26">
irb(main):002:0> game = Game.find(1)
  Game Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Game id: 1, home_team_user_id: 1, away_team_user_id: 1, home_score: "1", away_score: "2", winner_id: 1, loser_id: 1, created_at: "2016-04-02 12:27:26", updated_at: "2016-04-02 12:27:26">
irb(main):003:0> game.users
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "games_users" ON "users"."id" = "games_users"."user_id" WHERE "games_users"."game_id" = ?  [["game_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I'm thinking now that the User.id needs to be linked to each individual corresponding id from the Games table.

How can I set this up? Do I need to use the `has_many :through` association?

UPDATE:

Could it be as simple as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :games, :foreign_key => "home_team_user_id"
    has_many :games, :foreign_key => "away_team_user_id"


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end



class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "home_team_user_id"
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "away_team_user_id"
end
```

Because actually a User has many games but in that game he only has one team, the home or away team. In this logic I assigned the user_id to one of the custom foreign fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games,    class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'home_team_user_id'
  has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'away_team_user_id'
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_user,    class_name: "User", foreign_key: "home_team_user_id"
  belongs_to :away_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "away_team_user_id"
  # Rails anticipate foreign keys itself so, addig `foreign_keys` is not
  # necessary in this class as we've already mentioned `belongs_to :home_user`
end
```